# How do I make getters/setters in the main QWizard that are accessible to every QWizardPage?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QWizard being created in Qt Creator. My wizard pages are all custom and being promoted to custom classes. I have tried casting the parentWidget() as the main wizards type and I also tried passing in the parent through the QWizardPages constructor as the QWizard page type (MainWizard in my case).

Upon further investigation I have noticed that upon the creation of the QWizardPages, they are not receiving the parent object! This is done in the generated code (ui_mainwizard.h).

```
page1 = new IntroPage();
    page1->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("page1"));
    MainWizard->addPage(page1);
    wizardPage2 = new OptionsPage();
    wizardPage2->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("wizardPage2"));
    MainWizard->addPage(wizardPage2);
```

Etc....

So this means that my methods have no way of working! The variables I am needing to save are primarily QStrings that represent file names, and custom objects from some of my API classes. Are field mechanisms my best bet? Or maybe sometype of global object? I'm not really sure how to make all the pieces fit to where I can access these 'global' variables between all my QWizardPages. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe to subclass QWizard, add custom method for example setParameter which will save value to all child pages.

Comment: Is [fields](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwizard.html#registering-and-using-fields) what you're looking for?

Comment: @otopolsky I'm not sure, but I think that approach would disrupt my design flow...Is there an easy way to keep what I have without redesigning how I have everything set up in Qt Creator?

Comment: @thuga It seems that register field only handles QWidgets....I need to save QString, and other custom objects in my API classes

Comment: I never used the QWizard, but in Qt Creator you usually can promote widgets of standard types to custom types (right click in list -> promote to) if thats your problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by creating a `setDaddy(MainWizard *daddy)` in every one of my `QWizardPages`. In the constructor of the `MainWizard()`, I call `Page->setDaddy(this)`. Now every `QWizardPage` has access to all my setters/getters in the `MainWizard`.

Comment: what about using existing method setParent()? you could then cast (qobject cast) it to MainWizard.. but maybe its too hacky